# how will I display the string that i getText() on the textview

Tags: android, textview, gettext, settext

I want to put the scrapBookId that I getText on the textview, i am able to toast it and it returns to value, but once that i am putting it into textview there is no value, can someone help me please? Thank you

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.upload);
        addListenerOnButton();

        userid = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.userid);
        spinner = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spinnerscrapbookid);
        sbid = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.scrapbook_id);

        spinner.setOnItemSelectedListener(new OnItemSelectedListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
                    int position, long id) {
                // ---getting values from selected Spinner
                scrapBookId = ((TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.scrapBookId)).getText().toString();

                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "" + scrapBookId, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

            }

            @Override
            public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> arg0) {

            }
        });
        sbid.setText(scrapBookId);

        //---HashMap for SpinnerView
        scrapBookList = new ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>();

        SharedPreferences sp = PreferenceManager
                .getDefaultSharedPreferences(this);
        userid.setText(sp.getString("user_id", null));

        imageview = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageView);
        new LoadAllScrapBook().execute();
    }
```

Comment: listeners are not executed when they are declared, but when they are called. Also, the declaration does not block the execution of the rest of the function. `scrapBookId` in only defined once onItemSelected has been called.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll have to put that line into the `OnItemSelectedListener` as well:

```
sbid.setText(scrapBookId);
```

As you do it now, you are displaying the id in your `TextView` *before* the user has selected anything, so you will of course see the value you initialized `scrapBooxId` with.

Comment: already :) but i have another problem, can u check this question please? :( http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21909180/android-paint-the-dragged-sticker-on-the-canvas